# To bring or to take? (British English)

Tags: bring-take

I have a question about the use of these verbs, “bring” and “take”, in two specific situations.

1_*‘The postman took the letter to my house.’*

(context: I was not at home when saying this, but I was when the postman took the letter to my house.)

Should I use "take" or "bring"?

2_*‘The postman took the letter to the train station.’*

(context: I am saying this at the train station, but I was at the airport when the postman took the letter there.)

Again, should I use "take" or "bring"?

Thanks for any help!

P.S.: “…took the letter *there*.”, is it grammatical?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'll take you home / I'll bring you home.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64016/ill-take-you-home-ill-bring-you-home) But you should also consider [“Bring” vs. “take” in American English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3131/bring-vs-take-in-american-english) - we're not *that* much "separated by a common language"! Both verbs are fine for your two example contexts, regardless of whether the speaker / writer is British or American.

Comment: (In BrE at least, it's usually ***bring*** to wherever the speaker is located, and ***take*** for anywhere else. But that doesn't mean the opposite is always "incorrect",)

Comment: I think I would use _brought_ in both contexts. (1) Even when not at home, I would think of the postman _bringing_ the letter to me. (2) Speaking at the station, I would say 'brought the letter _here_'... and, yes, 'took the letter there' is correct.

Comment: (As I put it in a comment in another post) _Bring_ is the causative of _come_, and _take_ is the causative of _go_. Thus, _bring_ and _take_ are subject to most of the same peculiarities as _come_ and _go_, respectively. Read all about it in Fillmore's [Coming and Going](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/5-ComingAndGoing.pdf); if you find this heavy going, maybe it will come to you if you check out ["May We Come In?"](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/1-MayWeComeIn.pdf) and the rest of the [Deixis Lectures](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Deixis.html).

Answer (score 0):

There's an interesting twist in this question. Identifying the deictal centre is not easy in situation (1). Is it [out; time of speaking] or [in; time of delivery]? *I believe it can be user-defined in this case.*

Context will usually decree [place where speaking; time when speaking], so you are free to use 'brought' to indicate succinctly that you were in ('brought ... to my house') when the letter arrived.

......

In (2), I'd say 'took' doesn't work at all. A 'though I wasn't here; I was at the airport at the time' caveat would be necessary to point out you were elsewhere when the letter arrived at the station.

......

'There' can be used as a directional, just like prepositional phrases, after say V + NP (threw the ball / sent the parcel ...):

(took the parcel to the hospital / into the shop / across the Channel / home / there ...).

It can sometimes sound a little weak (I sent my clothes, my books, my furniture, and even  my unrivalled collection of foreign coins there).