# Do you bring or take someone to school?

Tags: word-choice

I'm writing a fanfic and I need to know this because I have a lot of lines where this gets brought up. These are the lines in question:

"Cole is cheerily running around the house, looking for Hank to take him to school."

"Usually, Hank takes him to school, but Cole can’t seem to find him anywhere."

"I will take you to the parent-teacher conference today."

"I should’ve let someone else take you to school."

Comment: ***Bring vs Take*** https://www.grammarly.com/blog/bring-vs-take/

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Bring" vs. "take" in American English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3131/bring-vs-take-in-american-english)